# How to handle errors in mio?

Tags: rust, mio

I am building a multithreaded async HTTP server on top of mio.

How should I handle events on client `TcpStream` connections?

- For `is_readable` it's pretty straightforward: I read the request and write the response.
- For other kinds I am not sure. Should I `shutdown()` the stream if I get `is_error` or `is_hup`? What about `is_none()`?

Comment: Have you seen [this series by Herman J. Radtke](http://hermanradtke.com/2015/07/12/my-basic-understanding-of-mio-and-async-io.html)? It contains useful information on error-handling in `mio`.

Comment: Thanks, that read was interesting. Unfortunately he doesn't talk about error handling much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All things that you mention have very precise meaning and map directly to POSIX/BSD Socket API. It's up to you to decide.

`is_hup` on Read mean the other side hanged-up it's sending side. Meaning it won't send you anything again. However it might have kept the reading open, and you might still want to send some data to it.

`shutdown` closes Reading/Writing/Both https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/enum.Shutdown.html , so it's up to you what and when you want to do.

`TcpStream` internally holds `FileDesc` and that will `close` the `fd` when you drop it, so if you don't `shutdown` manually everything will be closed anyway, as soon as you remove given `TcpStream` from usage. https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/src/libstd/sys/unix/fd.rs#L217